# How to make the user journey map more socializ-able and more integrated within the design process

Tags: social-interfaces, user-journey, journey-map

Right now a 2 person team maintains the user journey map for our mobile app. It sits on a miro board and the only time others in the wider product team or org see it is once a quarter at the most during a detailed run-through of assumptions and pain points.

we're hoping that we could make the user journey map more socializ-able and more integrated within the design process. My question is how do we do this?

One idea we had was to re-create an offline version in the office where everyone can see it. but given Covid this year people actually working at the office has drastically reduced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, the effect of COVID-19 and the transition into remote work has reduced the effectiveness of many UX artefacts that are often used to help people engage better with the information.

The next best thing is probably to make the information available within the intranet (if that's somewhere people visit frequently), or to build some interactivity with the customer/user journey and publicize it so that people have visibility of it and can help spread the word.

Of course, you have to take into consideration the effort required to do this and the outcome you want to achieve. Hopefully people within the organization want to know more about their customers and users and it is just about providing access to the information.

If you are still trying to make an argument for the case of user-centric design within the organisation, perhaps it is easier to start with less complex information like personas or direct analytics data that is smaller and easier to consume.